# Net::HTTPServerException causing Chef to fail

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, provisioning

I'm attempting to set up a Rails environment with Vagrant and Chef by following [this guide](https://gorails.com/guides/using-vagrant-for-rails-development). I've used it in the past with success.

When I run `vagrant up` it fails, and (I think) this is the relevant error:

`INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Parent not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes`

Googling "chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes" comes up with [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6159), but I'm not sure if it's relevant, and the solution is a little over my head to be honest.

I'm running Vagrant 1.8.1 and VirtualBox 5.0.20 r106931 on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Cheffile and Vagrantfile:

```
# Cheffile
  site "http://community.opscode.com/api/v1"

  cookbook 'apt'
  cookbook 'build-essential'
  cookbook 'mysql', '5.5.3'
  cookbook 'ruby_build'
  cookbook 'nodejs'
  cookbook 'rbenv', git: 'https://github.com/aminin/chef-rbenv'
  cookbook 'vim'

# Vagrantfile
  # -*- mode: ruby -*-
  # vi: set ft=ruby :

  VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

  Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    # Use Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr 64-bit as our operating system
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

    # Configurate the virtual machine to use 2GB of RAM
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
    end

    # Forward the Rails server default port to the host
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000

    # Use Chef Solo to provision our virtual machine
    config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
      chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks", "site-cookbooks"]

      chef.add_recipe "apt"
      chef.add_recipe "nodejs"
      chef.add_recipe "ruby_build"
      chef.add_recipe "rbenv::user"
      chef.add_recipe "rbenv::vagrant"
      chef.add_recipe "vim"
      chef.add_recipe "mysql::server"
      chef.add_recipe "mysql::client"

      # Install Ruby 2.2.1 and Bundler
      # Set an empty root password for MySQL to make things simple
      chef.json = {
        rbenv: {
          user_installs: [{
            user: 'vagrant',
            rubies: ["2.2.1"],
            global: "2.2.1",
            gems: {
              "2.2.1" => [
                { name: "bundler" }
              ]
            }
          }]
        },
        mysql: {
          server_root_password: ''
        }
      }
    end
  end
```

Plugin list:

```
j@DESKTOP-J5TQ03P MINGW64 ~
$ vagrant plugin list
vagrant-bindfs (0.3.2)
  - Version Constraint: 0.3.2
vagrant-librarian-chef-nochef (0.2.0)
vagrant-share (1.1.5, system)
vagrant-vbguest (0.11.0)
```

`vagrant up` output:

```
j@DESKTOP-J5TQ03P MINGW64 ~/dev/ruby/test
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: A newer version of the box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is available! You currently
==> default: have version '20160519.0.2'. The latest is version '20160601.0.0'. Run
==> default: `vagrant box update` to update.
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: test_default_1464890607987_76530
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Installing Chef cookbooks with Librarian-Chef...
==> default: Auto-generating node name for Chef...
==> default: The cookbook path 'C:/Users/j/dev/ruby/test/site-cookbooks' doesn't exist. Ignoring...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 3000 (guest) => 3000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.0.20) and guest (4.3.36) do not match.
stdin: is not a tty
 * Stopping VirtualBox Additions
   ...done.
stdin: is not a tty
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  acl at-spi2-core colord dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service dkms fakeroot
  fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core gcc gcc-4.8
  hicolor-icon-theme libasan0 libasound2 libasound2-data libatk-bridge2.0-0
  libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatomic1 libatspi2.0-0 libavahi-client3
  libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev
  libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module
  libcanberra0 libcolord1 libcolorhug1 libcups2 libdatrie1 libdconf1
  libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libexif12 libfakeroot
  libfontconfig1 libfontenc1 libgcc-4.8-dev libgd3 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa
  libgomp1 libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port10 libgraphite2-3
  libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgudev-1.0-0 libgusb2
  libharfbuzz0b libice6 libieee1284-3 libitm1 libjasper1 libjbig0
  libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libllvm3.4 libltdl7 libnotify-bin
  libnotify4 libogg0 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0
  libpciaccess0 libpixman-1-0 libquadmath0 libsane libsane-common libsm6
  libtdb1 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libtsan0 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libv4l-0
  libv4lconvert0 libvorbis0a libvorbisfile3 libvpx1 libwayland-client0
  libwayland-cursor0 libx11-xcb1 libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0
  libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1
  libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxfont1 libxi6
  libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxkbfile1 libxmu6 libxpm4 libxrandr2
  libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxt6 libxtst6 libxxf86vm1 linux-libc-dev
  manpages-dev notification-daemon sound-theme-freedesktop x11-common
  x11-xkb-utils xfonts-base xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils xserver-common
  xserver-xorg-core
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  virtualbox-guest-dkms* virtualbox-guest-utils* virtualbox-guest-x11*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 12.1 MB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 62991 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox-guest-dkms (4.3.36-dfsg-1+deb8u1ubuntu1.14.04.1) ...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  virtualbox-guest
Version: 4.3.36
Kernel:  3.13.0-86-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

vboxguest.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.13.0-86-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxsf.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.13.0-86-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxvideo.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.13.0-86-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 4.3.36
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Removing virtualbox-guest-x11 (4.3.36-dfsg-1+deb8u1ubuntu1.14.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for virtualbox-guest-x11 (4.3.36-dfsg-1+deb8u1ubuntu1.14.04.1) ...
Removing virtualbox-guest-utils (4.3.36-dfsg-1+deb8u1ubuntu1.14.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for virtualbox-guest-utils (4.3.36-dfsg-1+deb8u1ubuntu1.14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
stdin: is not a tty
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
dkms is already the newest version.
dkms set to manually installed.
linux-headers-3.13.0-86-generic is already the newest version.
linux-headers-3.13.0-86-generic set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  acl at-spi2-core colord dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service fontconfig
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core hicolor-icon-theme libasound2
  libasound2-data libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0
  libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcairo-gobject2
  libcairo2 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra0 libcolord1
  libcolorhug1 libcups2 libdatrie1 libdconf1 libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2
  libdrm-radeon1 libexif12 libfontconfig1 libfontenc1 libgd3
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
  libglapi-mesa libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port10 libgraphite2-3
  libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgudev-1.0-0 libgusb2
  libharfbuzz0b libice6 libieee1284-3 libjasper1 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8
  libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libllvm3.4 libltdl7 libnotify-bin libnotify4 libogg0
  libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpciaccess0
  libpixman-1-0 libsane libsane-common libsm6 libtdb1 libthai-data libthai0
  libtiff5 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libvorbis0a
  libvorbisfile3 libvpx1 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libx11-xcb1
  libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0
  libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1
  libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxfont1 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0
  libxkbfile1 libxmu6 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxt6
  libxtst6 libxxf86vm1 notification-daemon sound-theme-freedesktop x11-common
  x11-xkb-utils xfonts-base xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils xserver-common
  xserver-xorg-core
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Copy iso file C:\Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
stdin: is not a tty
mount: block device /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso is write-protected, mounting read-only
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 5.0.20 - guest version is 4.3.36
stdin: is not a tty
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.0.20 Guest Additions for Linux............
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules ...done.
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
Starting the VirtualBox Guest AdditionsInstalling the Window System drivers
Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping.
 ...done.
stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/Users/j/dev/ruby/test
    default: /tmp/vagrant-chef/c27f755861b699cfdd06b09fc9106dd7/cookbooks => C:/Users/j/dev/ruby/test/cookbooks
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
    default: Installing Chef (latest)...
==> default: Generating chef JSON and uploading...
==> default: Running chef-solo...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: [2016-06-02T18:05:53+00:00] INFO: Started chef-zero at chefzero://localhost:8889 with repository at /tmp/vagrant-chef/c27f755861b699cfdd06b09fc9106dd7
==> default:   One version per cookbook
==> default: [2016-06-02T18:05:53+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
==> default: Starting Chef Client, version 12.11.17
==> default: [2016-06-02T18:05:53+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.11.17 ***
==> default: [2016-06-02T18:05:53+00:00] INFO: Platform: x86_64-linux
==> default: [2016-06-02T18:05:53+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 6071
==> default: [2016-06-02T18:05:54+00:00] INFO: GET /organizations/chef/nodes/vagrant-f3082290
==> default: [2016-06-02T18:05:54+00:00] INFO: #<ChefZero::RestErrorResponse: 404: Object not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes/vagrant-f3082290>
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:91:in `rescue in get_data'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:83:in `get_data'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/endpoints/rest_object_endpoint.rb:18:in `get'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:62:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_router.rb:24:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:664:in `block in app'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:336:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:336:in `handle_socketless_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/socketless_server_map.rb:87:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/socketless_server_map.rb:33:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http/socketless_chef_zero_client.rb:154:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http.rb:305:in `block in send_http_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http.rb:336:in `block in retrying_http_errors'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http.rb:334:in `loop'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http.rb:334:in `retrying_http_errors'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http.rb:299:in `send_http_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http.rb:144:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http.rb:111:in `get'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/node.rb:604:in `load'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/node.rb:588:in `find_or_create'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/policy_builder/dynamic.rb:72:in `load_node'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/client.rb:465:in `load_node'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/client.rb:267:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:286:in `block in fork_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:274:in `fork'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:274:in `fork_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:239:in `block in run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:227:in `run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/client.rb:456:in `sleep_then_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/client.rb:443:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/client.rb:442:in `loop'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/client.rb:442:in `interval_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/client.rb:426:in `run_application'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:59:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:217:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
==> default: /usr/bin/chef-solo:52:in `load'
==> default: /usr/bin/chef-solo:52:in `<main>'
==> default: [2016-06-02T18:05:54+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Object not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes/vagrant-f3082290
==> default: [2016-06-02T18:05:54+00:00] INFO: POST /organizations/chef/nodes
==> default: --- POST BODY ---
==> default: {"name":"vagrant-f3082290","chef_environment":"_default","json_class":"Chef::Node","automatic":{},"normal":{},"chef_type":"node","default":{},"override":{},"run_list":[]}
==> default: --- END POST BODY ---
==> default: [2016-06-02T18:05:54+00:00] INFO: #<ChefZero::RestErrorResponse: 404: Parent not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes>
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:187:in `rescue in create_data'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:181:in `create_data'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/endpoints/rest_list_endpoint.rb:31:in `post'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/endpoints/nodes_endpoint.rb:24:in `post'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:62:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_router.rb:24:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:664:in `block in app'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:336:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:336:in `handle_socketless_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/socketless_server_map.rb:87:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/socketless_server_map.rb:33:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http/socketless_chef_zero_client.rb:154:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http.rb:305:in `block in send_http_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http.rb:336:in `block in retrying_http_errors'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http.rb:334:in `loop'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http.rb:334:in `retrying_http_errors'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http.rb:299:in `send_http_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http.rb:144:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http.rb:127:in `post'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/node.rb:639:in `create'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/node.rb:592:in `rescue in find_or_create'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/node.rb:588:in `find_or_create'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/policy_builder/dynamic.rb:72:in `load_node'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/client.rb:465:in `load_node'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/client.rb:267:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:286:in `block in fork_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:274:in `fork'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:274:in `fork_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:239:in `block in run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:227:in `run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/client.rb:456:in `sleep_then_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/client.rb:443:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/client.rb:442:in `loop'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/client.rb:442:in `interval_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/client.rb:426:in `run_application'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:59:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:217:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
==> default: /usr/bin/chef-solo:52:in `load'
==> default: /usr/bin/chef-solo:52:in `<main>'
==> default: [2016-06-02T18:05:54+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Parent not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: Chef encountered an error attempting to load the node data for "vagrant-f3082290"
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: Resource Not Found:
==> default: -------------------
==> default: The server returned a HTTP 404. This usually indicates that your chef_server_url is incorrect.
==> default: Relevant Config Settings:
==> default: -------------------------
==> default: chef_server_url "chefzero://localhost:8889"
==> default: Platform:
==> default: ---------
==> default: x86_64-linux
==> default: Running handlers:
==> default: [2016-06-02T18:05:54+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: Running handlers complete
==> default: [2016-06-02T18:05:54+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 seconds
==> default: [2016-06-02T18:05:54+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2016-06-02T18:05:54+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
==> default: [2016-06-02T18:05:54+00:00] ERROR: 404 "Not Found"
==> default: [2016-06-02T18:05:55+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Contents of `chef-stacktrace.out`:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo cat /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Generated at 2016-06-02 18:05:54 +0000
Net::HTTPServerException: 404 "Not Found"
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:119:in `error!'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http.rb:146:in `request'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/http.rb:127:in `post'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/node.rb:639:in `create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/node.rb:592:in `rescue in find_or_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/node.rb:588:in `find_or_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/policy_builder/dynamic.rb:72:in `load_node'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/client.rb:465:in `load_node'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/client.rb:267:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:286:in `block in fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:274:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:274:in `fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:239:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:227:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/client.rb:456:in `sleep_then_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/client.rb:443:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/client.rb:442:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/client.rb:442:in `interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/client.rb:426:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application.rb:59:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:217:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.17/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:52:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:52:in `<main>'vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Vagrant still installs nightly builds. Set your install channel to `stable` to get the current release instead.

Comment: Install channel for `vagrant-librarian-chef-nochef`? Or Vagrant itself?

Comment: It's part of the chef provisioner plugin that comes with Vagrant: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/chef_common.html

Comment: It says the default value of `channel` is `"stable"`.

Comment: The docs are incorrect, the default is still `current` (i.e. nightlies) in the latest release.